# Android Spinner with SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, sqliteopenhelper, android-spinner

I have used MyOnItemSelectedListener to populate items into the Spinner and it works. My problem is after this how to set the Database details in a a list view below Spinner. What code should be written in after onItemSelected?

Comment: Did your question has been answered?if yes, please post yor code here.

Answer (score 2):

in onItemSelected() method,you can build an array/cursor for fetching relative data from database depending on the spinner item selected.

Then you can set your listview with that array/cursor to get it populated with the database details according to the item selected into the spinner.

that is so simple!

Comment: pleasae accept the answer by clicking "check" mark on top left of this answer,if it was useful to you.